# Apache Traffic Server Local Environment

Tags: apache-traffic-server

I'm trying to setup a local environment that handles ESIs, caches, and supports a number of apache rules for vanity urls to mimic a production environment.

I'm using Apache Traffic Server, Apache 2.4.7, and Adobe Experience Manager 6. Our developers are having issues working locally due to all of the ESIs and device detection specific rewrites that are in our Akamai backed environments.

I have most of this stack working inside a redistributable vagrant chef/Ubuntu-14.04 VM. The issue we're having is that Apache Traffic Server is not seeing localhost as a fully qualified DNS entry.

Every request returns with Status Code:404 Not Found on Accelerator.

Has anyone every try to accomplish something similar?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traffic Server has it's own DNS resolver and does not examine /etc/hosts. IIRC there's an upstream bug report to fix that. You'll need to use "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost".

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I ended up doing. Then after a few weeks, localhost started working. Was that the bug fix?